# How do I get sal.h

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, sdk, header

I have been trying to compile a program with minw32, on win7. Every time I try to compile this, I get an error about sal.h missing. I have downloaded both Visual Studio c++ 2010 (Express) and have gotten the Microsoft Win7 SDK. Even after all this, I still haven't found that header file. Is there any place I could download it from?

Answer (score 11):

It's located in

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include" (VS 2008)
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include" (VS 2010)
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include" (VS 2012)
```

of course, you may want to adapt to your local setup paths.

Comment: What does a include in VS installation path help when one is trying to compile with MinGW?

Comment: @elmi - Because SAL Annotations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx) is part of Microsoft Visual C++ which ships with Microsoft Visual Studio, not part the Windows SDK nor any other Microsoft-provided SDK, whether you like or not.

Comment: Hm, so the answer would be, it is not possible to compile something out of the WinSDK with MingW (including DirectX-thingies)!?

Comment: Well, my answer is an answer to the question "How do I get sal.h". "How to compile XYZ without Visual C++ installed" would be another question I have not worked on.

Answer (score 5):

As the previous answer says, SAL is a Visual Studio thing. IMHO it's a great technology which helps the compiler understand the code so it can emit warnings when you do something wrong. Unfortunately, Microsoft [seems to own a patent on it so other compilers can't implement it](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/RFC-Starting-support-for-SAL-tp3466171p3544109.html) ☹. Even if you grab a copy of `sal.h` from your VS install I sincerely doubt it will work with mingw since it will translate the macros into attributes gcc/mingw doesn't understand.

I put together a small project called [Salieri](https://github.com/nemequ/salieri) a while back which is basically a portable version of the SAL header that just defines away the SAL macros. You won't get any of the benefits of SAL annotated code, but it should help you get code which uses SAL to compile on other compilers.

Sorry to promote my own project here, but I think it could be useful for a lot of people coming across this post.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/testtools/sal/inc/no_sal2.h) a less poetically named solution by Microsoft itself, extended to include [SAL 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/sal-2-annotations-for-windows-drivers). They plagiarised you ☹.