# fatal error: sal.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ui-automation

I know that there are other errors for certain header files with the same message of "No such file or directory", but my circumstances are a bit different as I will explain now.

I use the Code Blocks IDE and wanted to start using the UI Automation library. When I tried to include the header

```
#include UIAutomation.h
```

Code Blocks could not find the header. From there I looked around my computer and saw that the UIAutomation.h, UIAutomationCore.h... and the other UIAutomation headers were in an "Include" file in the "Microsoft SDKs" folder.... So I went to (Settings -> Compiler -> Search directories) and in there I added a new directory to the include folder where the UI Automation headers were:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include;

and Code Blocks found the headers. However... another error appeared:

```
fatal error: sal.h: No such file or directory
```

and I searched for the sal.h in the "\Include" folder I had just written code for and there was no sal.h file. I understood everything up until here... I had to check if I had a sal.h folder somewhere else on my computer and I did, in a file somewhere in my Visual Studio 10 IDE folders (just to let u guys know, I use code blocks cause I have been using it for a long time, and only downloaded VS10 recently to use spy++). So then I thought ok... I'll do the same thing I did before again so that I can include those files too, so I go back into the Search directories section and add the directory:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include

but from there a million different errors appeared, all refereeing to different issues. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? All I wanted to do was use the UI Automation headers so that I can start coding with the library, but that is proving to be a bit difficult...

Comment: If you add `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`, but actually use a different toolchain (e.g. GCC) with codeblocks there will be conflicts regarding the c++ standard header files.

Comment: oh... so how would you go about solving the problem so that you can use the UI Automation library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get sal.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434198/how-do-i-get-sal-h)

Comment: Any brackets around your UIAutomation.h include?

Comment: @SimonMourier It's not really a duplicate (mention of codeblocks IDE specifically).

Comment: @zoska yeah I put the brackets <> but I am seeing now that that is not the issue. the issue is that I am missing the sal.h file which is found in the VS2010 folder, and If I include the VS2010 folder, what I understand is that some of the files will be in direct conflict with the files code blocks has, hence I would have to take another approach

Comment: If you can't change the toolchain to MSVC you can also write your own sal.h. That's what I do in my cross platform projects. Normally only a few macros are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what one can get from this related Q&A: ['How do I get sal.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434198/how-do-i-get-sal-h) it's not possible to use this stuff with a different toolchain than MSVC (Visual Studio).

You may consider to configure MSVC as toolchain for this codeblocks project.

Comment: Oh... I see... that is a possible solution. Any Idea on how to do that configuration?

Comment: No sorry, I'm not very experienced with codeblocks. But it should be easily found in CB's documentation/user manuals.

Comment: If you want to thank me you could consider accepting the answer by clicking the white checkmark at the left ;)

Comment: hahah, definitly. I'm new to the site and didn't notice that checkmark option