# OpenMP + MPI Hybrid in C - compilation difficulty

Tags: c, windows, mpi, openmp

Have to compile something like the following code, (OpenMP + MPI in C)
I have very little experience with compilers, and been having major trouble with this
,need clear steps how to compile such code in windows
,very much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numprocs, rank, namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int iam = 0, np = 1;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

  #pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(iam, np)
  {
    np = omp_get_num_threads();
    iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d from process %d out of %d on %s\n",
           iam, np, rank, numprocs, processor_name);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile with MPI like any other library, and compilers have a specific OpenMP flag. Assuming you use MS-MPI and the Microsoft C/C++ compiler:

1. Add MPI include and library paths
   `/I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include"`  and `/libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64"`

   - Change `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI"` for wherever you installed MS-MPI
   - If on a 32 bit machine, repace `Lib\x64` with `Lib\x86`
2. Add the MPI library to the command line: `"msmpi.lib"`
3. Add the OpenMP flag to the command line: `/openmp`

```
cl /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include" /libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64" /openmp "msmpi.lib" /out:helloworld.exe helloworld.c
```

See Microsoft's documentation: [How to compile and run a simple MS-MPI program](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program/) and [/openmp (Enable OpenMP 2.0 Support)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw509c3b.aspx)

---

If you're using GNU tools (mingw or cygwin) then the same would apply: link MPI and add the OpenMP flag.

```
gcc -I"/path/to/MPI/include" -L"/path/to/MPI/include" -lmpi --openmp -o helloworld.exe helloworld.c
```

Note that you may need to change `-lmpi` to `-lmpich` if your library is a derivative of [MPICH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPICH).

Comment: thank you very much for your help, 
i ran the following line:
gcc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x86" -lmpi --openmp -o c.exe mpi.c

but i recieved the following error:
In file included from mpi.c:3:0:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include/mpi.h:50:17: fatal error: sal.h: No such file or directory
I would appreciate your help

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434198/how-do-i-get-sal-h) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434198/how-do-i-get-sal-h) question on sal.h