# Missing header file sal.h when calling mpi.h header file

Tags: mpi

I am using code block IDE to develop the mpi code but when I am compiling the code it is showing 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\mpi.h|54|fatal error: sal.h: No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Please can anyone help me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [How do I get sal.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434198/how-do-i-get-sal-h) for how to get `sal.h`.

That being said, from `mpi.h` :

```
#ifndef MSMPI_NO_SAL
#include <sal.h>
#endif
```

So you might want to define the `MSMPI_NO_SAL` macro and see if this workaround is good enough.